# How to enter on real time RSI value?

Tags: pine-script

One of my strategy is supposed to buy whenever the RSI/7 4h drops sharply down to a value of 15.

```
btc_4H = security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", close)
rsi_7_4H = rsi(btc_4H, 7)
```

and then I buy in when that happens in real time

```
strategy.entry ("long_id", strategy.long)
```

Trading View executes the entry, but only after the candle is closed. See picture.[image]

How can I buy in on real time RSI data? Do I need to change the "close" to anoher value?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I buy in on real time RSI data? Do I need to change the "close" to anoher value?

On the historical data your entry will enter position on the open of the next bar. When your strategy is in real-time, you can use `calc_on_every_tick` parameter set to `true` of strategy() function. This parameter allows the strategy to calculate on each update of realtime bars:

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, calc_on_every_tick = true)

....
```

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000628599